# Is there a way to unitary test the arguments passed to Model or Q object?

Tags: django, pytest, python-unittest, django-q

In my unit tests, I understand how I can mock objects per context, to avoid interacting with any kind of persistent datastore.

I can even mock the Q object to test how many times it has been called, which is really useful.

But I'm still uncomfortable with the fact that while I'm mocking my interaction with the datastores, I'm still assuming that my code works©, that the datastore (or the ORM in this case) is receiving the data correctly, through the "proper channels" so to speak.

Case in point:

```
# code to test
def related_stuff():
   return Stuff.objects.filter(
     parent__user__city_name="Las Vegas"
   )
   # more code...


 # testing above
 @mock.patch(f"{path_to}.Stuff.objects")
 def test_related_stuff(stuff_mock):
   stuff_mock.filter.return_value = stuff_mock
   stuff_mock.filter.assert_called_once_with(parent__user__city_name="Las Vegas")
```

How can I actually test that the `parent__user__city_name` lookup pattern is actually *correct* and wont result in an error? I'm assuming there's no way to test this without touching the datastore, but any opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could either ensure the database connection(s) are to eg. a memory sqlite instance, or maybe write a Djangon database adapter that straight out errors (or always returns an empty dataset) when a query is attempted.

With an adapter that always returns nothing, you can at least test that a query *would* work.